# Objective-C Async task. How can I run a function only once when called multiple times?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a function that gets called several times asynchronously. What I need it to do each time is wait several run loops (or just 0.1 seconds is fine) to make sure it doesn't get called from anywhere else. If it's called from somewhere else, skip the function and let the latest call execute the code (which in turn waits a small amount of time to check it's not called again).

It's a block of code that only needs to be executed once, but it needs the most up to date data to execute with. The likelihood of several important data updates coming concurrently is high. Think of it as a "check that no one with more important information should be running this code right now".

Is this possible? How would I go about this?

Comment: Don't you think this is rather risky? What if you set the delay at 0.1 seconds and the second call comes in 0.10001 seconds later?

Comment: This might help you: http://blog.spacemanlabs.com/2011/12/cancel-dispatch_after/

Comment: Similar: http://sebastienthiebaud.us/blog/ios/gcd/block/2014/04/09/diggint-into-gcd-1-cancel-dispatch-after.html

Comment: @matt it doesn't. It's actually a system call that triggers my function. This only happens once in a blue moon, but when it happens it seems to call it multiple times simultaneously, with the last time it is called being the one with the most correct data. Bit weird but yeah...

Comment: I had a problem like that with a notification arriving twice in quick succession and I used a solution similar to @simalone below.

Comment: However I think the best approach (which is what I ultimately did) was to redesign things so that it really didn't matter if I was called twice in quick succession. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

is this what you want?

```
[NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self selector:@selector(delayExecuteMethod) object:nil];
[self performSelector:@selector(delayExecuteMethod) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1];
```

Comment: Yes, nice and simple! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a category to handle this problem

[NSObject+XLCDelayedPerform.h](https://github.com/xlc/XLCUtils/blob/master/XLCUtils/NSObject%2BXLCDelayedPerform.h)

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface NSObject (XLCDelayedPerform)

- (void)xlc_setNeedsPerformSelector:(SEL)selector withObject:(id)obj;
- (void)xlc_setNeedsPerformSelector:(SEL)selector withObject:(id)obj withinInterval:(NSTimeInterval)interval;
- (void)xlc_performSelectorIfNeeded:(SEL)selector;

@end
```

[NSObject+XLCDelayedPerform.m](https://github.com/xlc/XLCUtils/blob/master/XLCUtils/NSObject%2BXLCDelayedPerform.m)

```
#import "NSObject+XLCDelayedPerform.h"

#import <objc/runtime.h>

@implementation NSObject (XLCDelayedPerform)

static const void *delayedPerformInfoKey = &delayedPerformInfoKey;

- (void)xlc_setNeedsPerformSelector:(SEL)selector withObject:(id)obj {
    [self xlc_setNeedsPerformSelector:selector withObject:obj withinInterval:0];
}

- (void)xlc_setNeedsPerformSelector:(SEL)selector withObject:(id)obj withinInterval:(NSTimeInterval)interval {
    NSMutableDictionary *dict = objc_getAssociatedObject(self, delayedPerformInfoKey);
    if (!dict) {
        dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
        objc_setAssociatedObject(self, delayedPerformInfoKey, dict, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN);
    }
    NSString *strSel = NSStringFromSelector(selector);
    id key = obj ? @[strSel, obj] : @[strSel];
    NSTimer *timer = dict[key];
    if (!timer) {
        timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:interval
                                                 target:self
                                               selector:@selector(xlc_delayedPerformSelectorOnTimer:)
                                               userInfo:key
                                                repeats:NO];
        dict[key] = timer;
    }
}

- (void)xlc_performSelectorIfNeeded:(SEL)selector {
    NSMutableDictionary *dict = objc_getAssociatedObject(self, delayedPerformInfoKey);
    NSString *strSel = NSStringFromSelector(selector);
    NSTimer *timer = dict[strSel];
    [timer fire];
}

#pragma mark - private

- (void)xlc_delayedPerformSelectorOnTimer:(NSTimer *)timer {
    NSArray *info = timer.userInfo;

    NSMutableDictionary *dict = objc_getAssociatedObject(self, delayedPerformInfoKey);
    [dict removeObjectForKey:info];

    id arg = info.count == 1 ? nil : info[1];

#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Warc-performSelector-leaks"
    [self performSelector:NSSelectorFromString(info[0]) withObject:arg];
#pragma clang diagnostic pop
}

@end
```

---

example

```
id obj = // something;
[obj xlc_setNeedsPerformSelector:@selector(dowork) withObject:nil];
[obj xlc_setNeedsPerformSelector:@selector(dowork) withObject:nil];

// [obj dowork] is called once on next runloop
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what kind of interface you're looking for, but using a private queue and a counter should allow you to build this kind of control. Here's sort of a proof-of-concept. You'll have to modify the procedure to suit your specific situation.

```
void coalesce_execution(dispatch_block_t executable,
                         dispatch_queue_t execution_queue,
                         double wait_interval)
{
    // Create a counter and a queue to synchronize access to it
    static unsigned int num_waiting = 0;
    static dispatch_queue_t wait_queue;
    static dispatch_once_t once_token;
    dispatch_once(&once_token, ^{
        wait_queue = dispatch_queue_create("your.label.here",
                                           DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT);
    });

    // Increment shared counter on queue
    dispatch_async(wait_queue, ^{
        num_waiting++;
    });

    // Wait, then decrement counter on queue
    dispatch_time_t wait_time = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW,
                                              (int64_t)(wait_interval * NSEC_PER_SEC));
    dispatch_after(wait_time, wait_queue, ^(void){
        num_waiting--;
        // If counter is zero, execute: nothing else came within the cutoff.
        if( 0 == num_waiting ){
            dispatch_async(execution_queue, executable);
        }
    });
}
```

Wiring up a button like so:

```
- (IBAction)executeCoalescing:(id)sender 
{

    NSLog(@"Clicked.");
    coalesce_executions(^{ NSLog(@"Got through");  },
                        dispatch_get_main_queue(), 0.5);

}
```

Gives output along these lines :

> 2014-06-04 03:40:33.374 CoalesceExecutions[98519:303] Clicked.
>   2014-06-04 03:40:33.565 CoalesceExecutions[98519:303] Clicked.
>   2014-06-04 03:40:34.066 CoalesceExecutions[98519:303] Got through
>   2014-06-04 03:40:34.600 CoalesceExecutions[98519:303] Clicked.
>   2014-06-04 03:40:34.802 CoalesceExecutions[98519:303] Clicked.
>   2014-06-04 03:40:35.304 CoalesceExecutions[98519:303] Got through
>   2014-06-04 03:40:35.342 CoalesceExecutions[98519:303] Clicked.
>   2014-06-04 03:40:35.623 CoalesceExecutions[98519:303] Clicked.
>   2014-06-04 03:40:36.085 CoalesceExecutions[98519:303] Clicked.
>   2014-06-04 03:40:36.585 CoalesceExecutions[98519:303] Got through
>   2014-06-04 03:40:40.955 CoalesceExecutions[98519:303] Clicked.
>   2014-06-04 03:40:41.135 CoalesceExecutions[98519:303] Clicked.
>   2014-06-04 03:40:41.315 CoalesceExecutions[98519:303] Clicked.
>   2014-06-04 03:40:41.518 CoalesceExecutions[98519:303] Clicked.
>   2014-06-04 03:40:41.698 CoalesceExecutions[98519:303] Clicked.
>   2014-06-04 03:40:41.878 CoalesceExecutions[98519:303] Clicked.
>   2014-06-04 03:40:42.047 CoalesceExecutions[98519:303] Clicked.
>   2014-06-04 03:40:42.238 CoalesceExecutions[98519:303] Clicked.
>   2014-06-04 03:40:42.429 CoalesceExecutions[98519:303] Clicked.
>   2014-06-04 03:40:42.598 CoalesceExecutions[98519:303] Clicked.
>   2014-06-04 03:40:42.789 CoalesceExecutions[98519:303] Clicked.
>   2014-06-04 03:40:42.980 CoalesceExecutions[98519:303] Clicked.
>   2014-06-04 03:40:43.482 CoalesceExecutions[98519:303] Got through
>   2014-06-04 03:40:44.894 CoalesceExecutions[98519:303] Clicked.
>   2014-06-04 03:40:45.395 CoalesceExecutions[98519:303] Got through
>   2014-06-04 03:40:46.019 CoalesceExecutions[98519:303] Clicked.
>   2014-06-04 03:40:46.520 CoalesceExecutions[98519:303] Got through
>   2014-06-04 03:40:48.054 CoalesceExecutions[98519:303] Clicked.
>   2014-06-04 03:40:48.346 CoalesceExecutions[98519:303] Clicked.
>   2014-06-04 03:40:48.847 CoalesceExecutions[98519:303] Got through
>   2014-06-04 03:40:49.055 CoalesceExecutions[98519:303] Clicked.
>   2014-06-04 03:40:49.336 CoalesceExecutions[98519:303] Clicked.
>   2014-06-04 03:40:49.837 CoalesceExecutions[98519:303] Got through